# "It's been a blast working with you guys for 5 years now." or "It's been a blast having worked with you guys for 5 years now."?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I think both are correct, but which one is better-structured and more suited for a formal context?

Comment: I’d probably say “for the last five years”  Also, define *formal*.  “Blast” and “you guys” aren’t very formal.  But a farewell email to coworkers isn’t a very formal thing anyway.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot. although i'm still uncertain about whether i should use "working" or "having worked"

Comment: I’d use “working” because the *blast* was the actual working with them.  it wasn’t somehow derived after the fact because you had worked with them.

Comment: got it. thanks a million

Comment: Yeah, the first is better.

Comment: If you want formal, you need to worry about a lot more than what you mention. Here is one of many possibilities: *It has been wonderful to work with you over the last five years.*

Comment: 'It's been nice knowing you.' Extremely common. You can check 'It's been nice having known you' in a Google search, and 'been nice having known you' on Google Ngrams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past Perfect Continuous/Past Perfect or?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150954/past-perfect-continuous-past-perfect-or)